# uglify with grunt-concurrent not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-concurrent

I'm trying to use grunt-concurrent to minify my javascript files in parallel. I also use usemin and ngmin.

When I use uglify without grunt-concurrent I get the expected result with this log output:

```
Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task

Running "uglify:dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js" (uglify) task
File dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js created.

Running "uglify:dist/scripts/external-non-angular-libraries.js" (uglify) task
File dist/scripts/external-non-angular-libraries.js created.

Running "uglify:dist/scripts/modules.js" (uglify) task
File dist/scripts/modules.js created.

Running "uglify:dist/scripts/scripts.js" (uglify) task
File dist/scripts/scripts.js created.
```

But when I try to execute this tasks using grunt-concurrent with that configuration:

```
    concurrent: {
        lessAndMinify: [
            'ngmin',
            'less'
        ],
        uglify: [
            'uglify:dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js',
            'uglify:dist/scripts/external-non-angular-libraries.js',
            'uglify:dist/scripts/modules.js',
            'uglify:dist/scripts/scripts.js',
            'uglify:dist/scripts/templates.js'
        ]
    },
```

I get the message that this tasks are not configured:

```
Running "concurrent:uglify" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "uglify:dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular\.js exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "uglify.dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular\.js" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings. Used --force, continuing.

Running "uglify:dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular\.js exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "uglify.dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular\.js" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
    Warning: Running "uglify:dist/scripts/modules.js" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.dist/scripts/modules\.js exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "uglify.dist/scripts/modules\.js" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings. Used --force, continuing.

Running "uglify:dist/scripts/modules.js" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.dist/scripts/modules\.js exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "uglify.dist/scripts/modules\.js" missing. Use --force to continue.
```

My build task configuration ist this:

```
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'ngtemplates',
    'copy:indexHtml',
    'replace',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'copy:dist',
    'copy:generated',
    'concurrent:lessAndMinify', // ngmin and less
//  'concurrent:uglify',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
```

The Question is, how can I make use of grunt-concurrent with uglify and usemin/ngmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usemin adds tasks to uglify on the fly but they are for whatever reason not visible in grunt-concurrent.
To solve this, you have to manually add the files to uglify:

```
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            },
            files: {
            }
        },

        // you have to add this manually!
        "dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js": "dist/scripts/jquery_and_angular.js",
        "dist/scripts/external-non-angular-libraries.js": "dist/scripts/external-non-angular-libraries.js",
        "dist/scripts/modules.js": "dist/scripts/modules.js",
        "dist/scripts/scripts.js": "dist/scripts/scripts.js",
        "dist/scripts/templates.js": "dist/scripts/templates.js"
    },
```

The problem is, that this is not dry. you have to configure it in the index.html, in grunt-concurrent and here in uglify..